# Identity Server 4 Error - 'Unrecognized SAML service provider - cannot find Client configuration'

Tags: identityserver4, saml-2.0, identity

I want to establish SAML connection between one external service provider with Identity server 4.

Steps which are performed.

1. Captured SAML metadata of IS4 application
2. Configured Service provider with IS4 metadata
3. While verification, I get below Error on IS4 application.

"Invalid Service Provider; Unrecognized SAML service provider - cannot find Client configuration".

Any idea what exactly I am missing here?

[image]

Thanks

(IS4 - Identity Server 4)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out root cause of this issue, for SAML Service provider below setting was in place due to this communication was failing.

```
AuthnRequestsSigned="false" 
WantAssertionsSigned="false"
```

So, I had change setting in 'Identity server - service provider' to turn off this validation.